# Android onActivityResult and onResume Lifecycle after low memory cleanup

Tags: android, android-activity, android-memory

I have two activities: ActivityA and ActivityB.  ActivityA starts Activity B for result, and expects a certain resultCode.  If it does not get it, ActivityA finishes. The idea is that this closes the application.

ActivityA also has an onResume method that does some stuff.  I do not want this stuff to be done if ActivityA decides to finish in the onActivityResult method.

This works in most cases, except in low memory situations where android removes both ActivityA and ActivityB from memory and reloads them.

For example: ActivityA starts ActivityB.  Background the application. Then android does its memory cleanup whatever.  We can simulate that in DDMS.

- Bring App To Foreground.
- onCreate() called for ActivityB
- Back Button to finish ActivityB
- onCreate() called for ActivityA
- onActivityResult() called for ActivityA
- result is a cancel, call finish()
- onResume() called for ActivityA
- on resume does stuff

These last two steps are not desirable.  Without the low memory issues, the normal workflow looks like this:

- Bring App to Foreground
- Back Button to finish ActivityB
- onActivityResult() called for ActivityA
- result is a cancel, call finish()

I have seen this on both a phone running Gingerbread and a Nexus 7 running Jellybean.

My first question: Am I missing something obvious in the Activity Lifecycle?

Failing that, is this the expected behavior from Android?  Is there an elegant way to resolve this, or do I have to hack something, or should I try a different approach all together?

Thanks in advance.  If anyone needs more information or code, just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a class member `private boolean mShouldFinished`. Set it to **true** in `onActivityResult` when called `finish`. In `onResume` check `mShouldFinished` and if **true** call `finish`.

Comment: That is what I did.  Except I named the variable ohGodWhy.  I was hoping there was a better solution :/

Comment: You can override onLowMemory in B and called finish there.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem.  B seems to be finishing correctly, and returns the correct result code to A.  It's A that is having trouble.  Also, I don't want to always finish() if there is low memory.  Ideally, the user could come back to B and complete the Activity and there would be no need to call finish() on either of them.

Comment: Well I am thinking if you called finish in  B before the system kills it, then A is still alive and would finish itself correctly.